# Html import menu

Tags: html, menu

Hy, I am new to html and I'm trying to make a site with a menu. The site has more pages so I have to copy the menu on all pages. What I am asking you is, there is no other way to import the menu (for example to import it from a menu.html page) so that i will not be forced to copy-paste it?

Comment: Why not using a CMS ? Drupal, Joomla (php), Jahia (java)... If you want to learn `HTML` my comment is useless, otherwise it can be helpful... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use master page.

this is your master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
 CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Demos.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        ***<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
          Text="Your Content Here:"  />***
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder 
          ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the label will be shown in all the pages that use this master pages
the thing that will be changed is the things in the "ContentPlaceHolder1"

this is ur html page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myContentPage.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="Demos.myContentPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" 
  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="This is from the content page" 
    BackColor="YellowGreen" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

read about it here:
http://webmaster.org.il/articles/aspnet-masterpage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

Comment: @GilFitussi : OP not include any .net tag or c# programming language. expecting only a html solution.

Answer (score 0):

create one menu.html page and include all menu items in this page and then

```
<!--#include file="menu.html"-->
```

this will do the job for you.Keep both file in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery 
add in your HTML  `<div id="menu"></div>`
and in javascript

```
 $(function(){ $( "#menu" ).load( "menu.html" );  })
```

and  inside `menu.html`  build your menu inside it.

for css use external CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner in web development. It is easy to use IFRAME.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Your menu-->
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="iframe_a">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="iframe_a">Yahoo</a>
<!--menu end-->

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Go through [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) for reference... All the best